# Missing feature in new review format

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm not loving the new format of the review queues. Putting aside the fact that I can't see any benefit from the change (apart from the extra exercise that my finger gets), the main thing that's bugging me is that there is now no direct link back to the main questions page.
My memory is short (yes, even last week is fuzzy) but I'm sure the previous format had the side panel which contained the 'questions' link. Any chance we could get this restored?

Comment: I think it is a [network-wide update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360198/visual-design-changes-to-the-review-queues). It does look like it's going to take some getting used to. Reviewing answers now especially has been made less straightforward, because the question doesn't simply appear under the post being reviewed any more.

Answer (score 2):

Fleshing my comment out as an answer with snaps.

I think it is a [network-wide update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360198/visual-design-changes-to-the-review-queues). It does look like it's going to take some getting used to. Reviewing answers now especially has been made less straightforward, because the question doesn't simply appear under the post being reviewed any more.

One of the things I find hard to adjust to is that the last editor of the post is shown in place of the original poster. Screen snaps of an answer review I am looking at:

[image]

First I look at the answer under review. Then I toggle to the question and... wait what? [ひろゆき](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E3%81%91%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%BF%E3%81%A1#h4_1)！ My profile picture and username appear where the question poster usually is. それを投稿した記憶はないけど。Looking up, I see the OP, date stamp and whatnot. The information is all there, granted, but its presentation and the overall layout have been made a lot less intuitive. In contrast, the normal post format has not changed:

[image]

Also in an answer review the action panel only shows under the "Answer" tab not the "Question" tab, which makes sense because apparently they want us to go back to the answer after taking a look at the question. But the tabs are very inconspicuous and the tab content is not framed. Thus it is hard to tell at first this is a tabbed view.

[image]